# change active class on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Hi Developer**, I want to know how to add Active class on next child on specific scroll amount like 100px. how I can define in jquery? if anyone helps me that would be good for me.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <ul class="slider">

<li class="active"> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>

    <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>

        <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>

            <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>

                <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>

                    <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>
  </ul>





<script>
 
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
       $('.section1 li').addClass('active');
    } else {
       $('.section1 li').removeClass('active');
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: <script>
 
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
       $('.section1 li').addClass('active');
    } else {
       $('.section1 li').removeClass('active');
    }
});

</script>

Comment: i tried this one

Comment: your code is working fine what do you want exactly.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<style>
 body{ overflow-x: hidden; padding-top: 50px; }

.slider{ padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
.slider li{ display: block;padding: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px; }
.active {
    background-color: #4a3c31e3;
    color: #fff;
}
.active {
    position: relative;
    right: -100%; display: block;
    width: 100%;   opacity: 1; visibility: visible;
    background: blue;
    -webkit-animation: slide 1s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation: slide 1s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    100% { right: 0%; }
}
@keyframes slide {
    100% { right: 0%; }
}

</style>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slider">
    
    <li class="active"> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>

        <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>

            <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>

                <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>

                    <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>

                        <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>  <li> Rationpora repellat recusandae mollitia, amet. Qui, minima ad ullam.</li>
  </ul>



<script>
 
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
       $('.section1 li').addClass('active');
    } else {
       $('.section1 li').removeClass('active');
    }
});

</script>


<script> 
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var timeStart = 0;
 function wheely(e) {
  var y = e.originalEvent.deltaY;
  var timeStop = new Date().getTime();
  var timeDiff = timeStop - timeStart;
  if (timeDiff > 200) {
   if (y > 0) {
    nextSlide();
   }
   if (y < 0) {
    prevSlide();
   }
  }
  timeStart = timeStop;
 }
 function prevSlide() {
  if ($('.active').is(':first-child')) {
   if (!$('.slider').hasClass('dragging')) {
    $('.slide:first-child').addClass('bounce');
    setTimeout(function() {
     $('.slide:first-child').removeClass('bounce');
    }, 300);
   }
  } else {
   $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('queue').prev().removeClass('prev').addClass('active');
  }
 }
 function nextSlide() {
  if ($('.active').is(':last-child')) {
   if (!$('.slider').hasClass('dragging')) {
    $('.slide:last-child').addClass('bounce');
    setTimeout(function() {
     $('.slide:last-child').removeClass('bounce');
    }, 300);
   }
  } else {
   $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('prev').next().removeClass('queue').addClass('active');
  }
 }
 function hotkeys(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
   prevSlide();
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
   e.preventDefault();
   nextSlide();
  }
 }
 function dragStart(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.type == 'touchstart') {
   $(document).off('mousedown', dragStart);
   startPoint = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
  } else {
   startPoint = e.pageY;
  }
  dragDist = 0;
  $(document).on('touchmove mousemove', dragMove);
 }
 function dragMove(e) {
  if (e.type == 'touchmove') {
   var movePoint = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
  } else {
   var movePoint = e.pageY;
  }
  dragDist = (movePoint - startPoint) / $('.slider').height() * 100;
  $('.slider').addClass('dragging');
  $('.slide, .bg').css({
   transition: '0ms'
  });
  if (dragDist < 0) {
   $('.active .bg').css({
    opacity: 1 + (dragDist / 200)
   });
   $('.active').css({
    transform: 'translate3d(0,' + (dragDist / 2) + '%,0)'
   }).next().css({
    transform: 'translate3d(0,' + (100 + dragDist) + '%,0)'
   });
  }
  if (dragDist > 0) {
   $('.active').css({
    transform: 'translate3d(0,' + dragDist + '%,0)'
   }).prev().css({
    animation: 'none',
    transform: 'translate3d(0,' + (-50 + dragDist / 2) + '%,0)'
   }).find('.bg').css({
    opacity: 0.5 + (dragDist / 200)
   });
  }
 }
 function dragEnd() {
  $(document).off('touchmove mousemove', dragMove);
  $('.slide, .bg').removeAttr('style');
  if (dragDist > 20) {
   prevSlide();
  }
  if (dragDist < -20) {
   nextSlide();
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
   $('.slider').removeClass('dragging');
  }, 800);
 }
 $(document).on('wheel', wheely);
 $(document).on('keydown', hotkeys);
 $(document).on('touchstart mousedown', dragStart);
 $(document).on('touchend mouseup', dragEnd);
});
 </script> 
 
</body>
</html>
```